# Mage registry key "_singleton/ambase/feed" already exists

Tags: register, compiler, singleton

One of the extension from Amasty was already installed in my website. I've installed another extension OPC and now I'm getting the error `Mage registry key "_singleton/ambase/feed" already exists`.

I've tried deleting cache folders, disabling compiler by command line

```
>php -f shell/compiler.php disable
>php -f shell/compiler.php clear
```

Still, I'm not able to login to Admin panel.
I've searched for `Mage::register('_singleton/amba` in my project folder but I don't find this code present in any of the folders.

Is that possible I can update this registry variable in database somehow?

Comment: Clear your var/session folder

Comment: I've tried clearing var/session too.

Comment: I disabled Amasty_Base.xml and also Amasty_Feed.xml but it's still not working. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Amasty_Base module via corresponding XML file, clear the cache folder.  Then log in, disable compilation, check the OPC cache and then enable the module back.